# Image with mask

Tags: swift, mask

I have image with logo and image with QR code. How can I join its together to get image like below?

[image]

It's some kind of masking as I understand, but I have no idea what exactly I have to do. Any help?

Comment: Why should you want to manipulate the QR?

Comment: for design purposes

Comment: But then your QR wouldn't work anymore, right?

Comment: it's not exactly true, but any way in this case this image is just funky image, not QR code

Comment: you can create any kinda shape of mask by e.g. defining a bezier-curve.

Comment: _it's not exactly true_ maybe you are right.. anyways I like the idea behind this ;)